# String.Join and/or Enumerable.Aggregate<string> support in EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, npgsql

I currently face the situation, that i need to allow the user to customly search for various properties of a given Entity.

The problem i currently face is that `String.Join` would be required to join those fields into one single searchable string.

### Example:

Given the following classes

```
public class A
{
    public string Example { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Collection<B> Bs { get; set; }
}
public class B
{
    public string Something { get; set; }
    public string Else { get; set; }
}
```

a User might want to query the following:

```
new string[] { "A.Example", "A.Bs.Select((b) => b.Else" }
```

The problem now: To join these together, I would have to use either Join or Aggregate to build the expression from `Bs` as the number of children cannot be known during build time. However, both are not supported by EntityFramework (With NpgSql).

The current code to concat them is the following:

```
System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression WrapExpression(IEnumerable<System.Linq.Expressions.Expression> expressions)
{
    // Create Range (Param 1, IEnumerable<string>)
    var aggregateArrayExpression = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(string), expressions);
    // Create Aggregate Lambda (Param 2,Func<string, string, string>)
    var aggregateConcatArrayExpression = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(string), enumerableAggregateLambdaParam1, percentConstant, enumerableAggregateLambdaParam2);
    var aggregateConcatExpression = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(stringConcatMethod, aggregateConcatArrayExpression);
    var lambda = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda(aggregateConcatExpression, enumerableAggregateLambdaParam1, enumerableAggregateLambdaParam2);
    // Create the actual Aggregate
    var aggregateCallExpression = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(enumerableAggregate, aggregateArrayExpression, lambda);
    // Append constant left & right
    var concatArrayExpression = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(string), percentConstant, aggregateCallExpression, percentConstant);
    var concatExpression = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(stringConcatMethod, concatArrayExpression);
    return concatExpression;
}
```

I need to avoid local sorting, as the expected "default" amount of entries can quickly exceed the *100 000*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems like you want to allow your users to basically express arbitrary LINQ queries... in strings. Regardless of joining, have you already written some sort of parser to actually implement this (and considered security implications)?

Comment: If arbitrary LINQ is really what you want, you may want to consider actually compiling the user-provided string with Roslyn into C# code and then running that. It wouldn't be fast but with some caching it may work.

Comment: The expressions do not get more complicated then this. The whole thing really boils down to "Take theese properties and do a DBLike on them". It may even be smarter to do it without concatinating though. Thanks to taht, the parser really is just "split string at '.' and navigate the Property Path down".

Comment: Reasoning in the end is for Text-Search in EF6 Objects. If you got a better idea, i am open to solutions that would work too for that scenario. Requirements are: User can enter text and choose the properties that are relevant to his search query

Comment: I don't know, in your example above you have `A.Bs.Select((b) => b.Else`, which seems like full-on free expression LINQ... That definitely seems way beyond "split at '.' and navigate the Property Path down"...

Comment: You may be going about this the wrong way - it seems that you're basically looking to do full-text search. Database contain specific support for that - including specialized indices for efficiency - and are probably a much better choice than a whole user-facing query language as you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm not sure how far EF6 will take you (I have no idea of full-text search capabilities there), but I do know that EF Core provides some support for FREETEXT(), for example (assuming you're using SQL Server). In any case you may want to read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search.

Comment: Query above was adjusted to allow readers to understand what is going on. In hindsight, not my best idea. Thanks for your Input, probably going to have to rework this stuff then